# Create a query to fetch customer from product sold

Tags: mysql, database

query to select customers who bought product 'a' but did
not buy products 'b'. (without using sub selects) Table 1 = List of
Customers, Table 2 = Products sold to customers (remember if a customer
bought product 'b' we want to exclude them from the result)
only in one query

Comment: what do the tables look like?  what have you tried?

Comment: Does product 'a' change at all? Have you tried using LIKE '%a%'?

Comment: smells like teen spirit... I mean... homework

Comment: Hi Dave
Customer table 
c_id, c_name

Product Sold table contains
id, p_id,c_id
p_id (is product id ) and c_id is (customer id)

Comment: This is a job interview question, verbatim. I just got the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A subquery or a join will both work.

SELECT * FROM Table_1 "t1" JOIN Table_2 "t2" USING (customer)
WHERE t1.customer = t2.customer
AND product != "b";

something like that?